# How to fire Property Changed with an Enum Property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

I have a standard Enum that will either be Yes or No:

```
public enum YesOrNo
{
   Yes,
   No
}
```

My base Model Class has a YesOrNo property like this:

```
public class Group : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private YesOrNo groupOperator;
  public YesOrNo GroupOperator
  {
    get
    {
      return this.groupOperator;
    }
    set
    {
      this.groupOperator = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("GroupOperator");
    }
  }
```

In my View, I am using a ToggleSwitch, similar to a slider you would see on a Mobile phone. Sliding back and forth should effectively reassign the value of the Enum. So it will default as Yes and sliding the toggle will set the Enum value to No and alternatively.

If I were to have a test method that reassigns the Enum when the Checked command is hit, the PropertyChanged event is fired so I know that is technically working. I am just wondering how I could go about alternating values in the Enum.

This is the ToggleButton in my XAML:

```
<ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource ToggleViewSwitch}" Command="{Binding SetOperatorCommand, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

And this is my Main View Model, where I hold the Command and the test method to assign the value manually:

```
  private bool isChecked = false;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get
        {
            return this.isChecked;
        }
        set
        {
            this.isChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
        }
    }

 private RelayCommand setOperatorCommand;
    public ICommand SetOperatorCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.setOperatorCommand == null)
            {
                this.setOperatorCommand = new RelayCommand(
                    x => ToggleGroupOperator());
            }
            return this.setOperatorCommand;
        }
    }

    private void ToggleGroupOperator()
    {
        if (IsChecked)
        {
            TopLevelGroup.GroupOperator = YesNo.No;
        }
        else
        {
            TopLevelGroup.GroupOperator = YesNo.Yes;
        }
    }
```

Comment: IsChecked is to know if the button has been toggled.

Comment: Is there any reason you're using an enum rather than just a bool?

Comment: If you want direct binding you could use an EnumToBooleanConverter?

Comment: If you really want an enum, you don't need a converter. You have a viewmodel. Make the backing field of type YesOrNo and translate in the get/set. Or wrap the true false with a separate field which is YesNo if you intend serialising and your plan is a "Yes" or "No" as a string.

Comment: You usually don't need a Command for a ToggleButton. Just have a TwoWay Binding to its IsChecked property. Note also that the IsChecked property of a WPF ToggleButton already binds TwoWay by default, so you already have everything in place. Just update GroupOperator in the IsChecked property setter.

Comment: These answers to avoid converters and update the get / set to do the work of enum manipulation is bad. I'll probably get push back but I don't care. It's bad code practice, it's bad code readability, it's bad for code reuse, and it's not what the type of translation work the ViewModel is intended for.  Either make it a True or False completely or use the converter, which is what the converter is intended for.

Answer (score 0):

First make a Converter...

```
public class YesOrNoToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => (value is YesOrNo yesOrNo && yesOrNo == YesOrNo.Yes) ? true : false;

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => (value is bool isYes && isYes) ? YesOrNo.Yes : YesOrNo.No;
}
```

Then reference the converter during binding...

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Converters:YesOrNoToBooleanConverter x:Key="YesOrNoToBooleanConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding GroupOperator, Converter={StaticResource YesOrNoToBooleanConverter}}" />
</Grid>
```

This will allow your ViewModel to remain using the enum without any overhead and the view to bind without any overhead; leave this binding manipulation work to converters.